# Jest Angular svg template

Tags: angular, svg, jestjs

I have several components in my Angular 9 app that have their templates defined in svg file like `templateUrl: './eye.component.svg'`.

When I run tests it errors

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
>
> Jest encountered an unexpected token
>
> This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.
>
> By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".
>
> Here's what you can do:
>
> ```
> • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
> • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
> • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.
> ```

How is this supposed to be fixed? It's still a template which I need to test, but now I cannot even start these tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out that I simply had to extend `jest.config.js` `transform` and `moduleFileExtentions` with `svg` and now it works just fine.

Here is how the config looks like after changes

```
module.exports = {
  testMatch: ['**/+(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|js)?(x)'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|js|html|svg)$': 'ts-jest'
  },
  resolver: '@nrwl/jest/plugins/resolver',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js', 'html', 'svg'],
  coverageReporters: ['html']
};
```

Comment: could you explain what you added in the transform? I couldn't get it to work and decided to mock my components for the time being

Answer (score 1):

In your Jest config for `ts-jest` you will likely have `stringifyContentPathRegex` - try adding `svg` to that value e.g.

```js
stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.(html|svg)$'
```

Example / more specifically:

```json
"globals": {
  "ts-jest": {
    "tsconfig": "<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json",
    "stringifyContentPathRegex": "\\.(html|svg)$"
  }
}
```

Notes

- This worked for an Angular 12.x project
- And fwiw I tried various things including the accepted answer above, which didn't quite work for my case.